# Implement navmesh for climbing cliffs and walls

Tags: unity, movement, raycasting, navmesh

I am trying to implement dynamic wall climbing similar to Conan exiles and Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild.

My system as of now uses a raycast to get the direction of a geometry's normal, and I make the player face that. I send another raycast in the direction of the players input, which takes the hit point, and lerps the player to that ray's hit position on the geometry.

Although this system works well on a flat wall it struggles a lot on complex geometry such as a bumpy cliff, and constantly hangs on small edges.

I recently saw [this video from the cancelled game Worlds Adrift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbNxBXaBol0) that seems to implement some sort of navmesh by making a flat plane that follows the terrain's normals. This allows the player to climb over gaps and complex geometry as if it was a smooth surface.

[image: Clip from Worlds Adrift showing navmesh patch]

I don't completely understand how they managed this, and I was wondering if someone who is knowledgeable about these things could explain how I could implement something like this in Unity.

Comment: It looks to me like they're doing something not too different from what you're doing now. Stepping out at an offset from the player's position and using a ray or shape query to find where a player at that shifted position would touch the wall. They do this for a grid of possible shifts, then connect the points they discovered into a mesh. The art is in figuring out how to structure those tests to correctly find hits near sharp corners, where your sweep might be liable to miss or start inside the obstacle, and exclude tight spaces where the character wouldn't fit.

Comment: I have never tried this, but is it possible to rotate the wall so it's flat, run Unity's nav-mesh generator on it, and then rotate the wall + nav-mesh back upright? Probably not, but worth looking into.

Comment: I'm not sure what having a navmesh would accomplish though, is that not just for simple pathfinding? Does it work for complex geometry surfaces?